# What is the HTML5 Video Buffering Amount on Autoplay

Tags: html, video

How much does an HTML5 Video set to `autoplay` buffer before it plays? Does it wait until it loads all of the video, or just a few seconds, a percentage or enough to guess how long it will take to load the rest? All [the W3C article](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html) seems to say is:

> "Instructs the UA to automatically begin playback of the video as soon
>   as it can do so without stopping."

Comment: Seems like it loads all or most of the video so the experience is seamless

Comment: Depends on the browser each one has a different take on that and some other related details based on loosely interpreted specs.

Answer (score 1):

An in depth explanation is available here:  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#concept-media-load-algorithm

The resource selection algorithm defined above describes exactly when the networkState attribute changes value and what events fire to indicate changes in this state.

All media elements have an autoplaying flag, which must begin in the true state, and a delaying-the-load-event flag, which must begin in the false state. While the delaying-the-load-event flag is true, the element must delay the load event of its document.

When the load() method on a media element is invoked, the user agent must run the media element load algorithm.

Every 350ms (±200ms) or for every byte received, whichever is least frequent, the progress event is fired.

Once enough of the media data has been fetched to determine the duration of the media resource, its dimensions, and other metadata, this indicates that the resource is usable and prompts the user agent to update the readyState to HAVE_METADATA and render the interface with the timeline and playback controls.  At which point the readyState attribute reaches HAVE_CURRENT_DATA which in turn triggers the element's delaying-the-load-event flag to false.

How this is implemented is dependent upon the interface.

Comment: Imtrying to post from my phone right now so most of my answer was just copy pasted from the aforementioned link.